# AVMutableComposition not allowing to add 4 video track

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

i am working with AVFoundation framework. I just want to add three videos to merge as a single video, but problem is i'm not able to add three videos. I want to know how many video we can add using AVMutableComposition. Is it allow to add more then 2 videos. Any help ?

here is my code

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// Add video tracks 1 to mutable compositon//
/////////////////////////////////////////////
let firstTrack = compostion.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
do{
    try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset1.duration),
            ofTrack: videoAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)
}
catch{
    print("failed to add first track")
}
print("Time to add 1 track\(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset1.duration))")

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// Add video tracks 2 to mutable compositon//
/////////////////////////////////////////////
let secondTrack = compostion.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
do{
    try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset2.duration),
            ofTrack: videoAsset2.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: videoAsset1.duration)
}
catch{
    print("failed to add second track")
}
print("Time to add second track\(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset2.duration))")
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// Add video tracks 3 to mutable compositon//
/////////////////////////////////////////////
let thirdTrack = compostion.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
do{
    try thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset3.duration), ofTrack: videoAsset3.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: videoAsset2.duration)
}
catch{
    print("failed to add third track")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// Add video tracks 3 to mutable compositon//
/////////////////////////////////////////////
let thirdTrack = compostion.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
do{
    try thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset3.duration), ofTrack: videoAsset3.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: videoAsset2.duration)
}
catch{
    print("failed to add third track")
}
```

You're trying to add the third video at atTime: videoAsset2.duration, which may already have a video at that point in time.

Assume Video 1 is 10 seconds and Video 2 is 5 seconds. You're literally trying to insert your 3rd video at 5 seconds in, which is half way through video 1 on the track where there is already an asset.

Fortunately it's an easy fix.

Personally, I maintain an insertion time like this:

```
var insertionTime : CMTime = kCMTimeZero
```

Then every time you successfully add a video, you can increment the insertionTime

```
insertionTime = CMTimeAdd(insertionTime, VideoAsset1.duration)
```

And from there, just use

```
try thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset3.duration), ofTrack: videoAsset3.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: insertionTime)
```

As a bonus with this approach, you can actually rewrite your code to use a loop and an array of video assets which makes it more reusable too.

Comment: Thanks , good answer . but i have previously solved this. This was my mistake.